# Is there a way to stop Canvas fillText function from rewriting on top?

Tags: javascript, php, html, pdf, canvas

Hello and thank you for the help!

I am developing a live PDF editor, where user's can fill out typical form inputs and see it auto-populate in their browser. It works successfully, however every time a user types in a field, it is over-writting over and over again making it appear bold.

here is an input example where I am capturing the value 'onkeyup'

```
<div class="col-12 mb-3">
     <p class="h3 mb-3 border-bottom">
          Stock
     </p
     <input class="form-control" type="text" value=""
         id="stock" onkeyup="editThisRow('stock')">
</div>
```

here is the function where I am checking the ID and using fillText to populate the value on canvas

```
  //function to change form fields
    const editThisRow = (idPassedAsParam) => {

        let thisRow = document.getElementById(idPassedAsParam);

        if (thisRow.id === 'projname') {
            doc.text(thisRow.value, 10, 10);
            ctx.fillText(thisRow.value, 85, 260);
        } else if (thisRow.id === 'sizepages') {
            doc.text(thisRow.value, 20, 20);
            ctx.fillText(thisRow.value, 85, 280);
        ...
```

here is a function I made that can clear all elements written by the user. It will clear both form values and canvas generated text

```
 //function to clear input on form
    const clearForm = () => {
        canvas.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    };
```

Below is a screenshot where you can see the form on the right and the PDF template on the left, the generated text starts to appear bold as it is overwriting itself on every key press

---

[image]

Comment: You could try "clearing" the field (similar to your `clearForm()` except just for 1 field) before drawing text to it. Inside `editThisRow()`

Comment: "Clear all. Redraw all".